# initial probability , 2rd drawn is red ball

Tags: probability

There are $2$ red and $4$ blue balls. One ball each time without replacement is drawn. What is the probability that the $2$nd drawn is red ball?

The answer is treated as if it's the initial drawn. Why?

Comment: Put labels on the balls, to make them distinct. All orders of drawing are equally likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$st ball can be drawn in $6$ ways. $2$nd ball can be drawn in $5$ ways as 'no replacement' condition is given. Total possibilities : $6*5=30$

Number of ways of drawing a red ball in 2nd draw has two possibilities. A red ball has already been drawn in first draw or it hasn't been drawn in first draw. So number of such possibilities : $^4C_1*^2C_1 + ^2C_1*^1C_1 = 10$

So probability would be : $\frac{10}{30} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: And so what? $ $

Comment: @Did Patience :)

Comment: Ach so. And now the same result with the same method for the 7th ball drawn...